# Using annotation to bind data

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Is it possible to do the same kind of behavior as this :

```
protected void onBind(HttpServletRequest request, Object command, BindException bindException) throws Exception {
    Invoice invoice = (Invoice) command;

    invoice.getLineItems().removeAll(Collections.singletonList(null));
}
```

When using annotation ?
I'm using the @controller annotation so i don't have the onBind function.  I want to manipute a List of element (remove item from the list).

Answer (score 1):

New way is to annotate method with [`@InitBinder`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/InitBinder.html) annotation:

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        ...
}
```

Also you may register `PropertyEditor` for transforming values by calling [`WebDataBinder.registerCustomEditor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/validation/DataBinder.html#registerCustomEditor%28java.lang.Class,%20java.beans.PropertyEditor%29) method. Also for transforming to collections there is [`CustomCollectionEditor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/propertyeditors/CustomCollectionEditor.html) which may be convenient.